# RestEasy how to get Netty Channel?

Tags: netty, resteasy, channel

I want to get the netty channel to do something in the Function of @DELETE:

@DELETE

@Path("/file/{path}")

@Produces("application/json;charset=UTF-8")

public Response deleteFile(

```
@PathParam("path") String path,

@QueryParam(value = "access") String access,

@Context HttpResponse httpResponse)
```

{

```
//i want to get the netty channel to do something.
```

}

but can't get.
I saw the resource code of RestEasy:

public Object invoke(HttpRequest request, HttpResponse httpResponse, Object resource) throws Failure, ApplicationException

{

```
  Object[] args = injectArguments(request, httpResponse);

  GeneralValidator validator = GeneralValidator.class.cast(request.getAttribute(GeneralValidator.class.getName()));
  if (validator != null)
  {
     validator.validateAllParameters(request, resource, method.getMethod(), args);
  }

  Method invokedMethod = method.getMethod();
  if (!invokedMethod.getDeclaringClass().isAssignableFrom(resource.getClass()))
  {
     // invokedMethod is for when the target object might be a proxy and
     // resteasy is getting the bean class to introspect.
     // In other words ResourceMethod.getMethod() does not have the same declared class as the proxy:
     // An example is a proxied Spring bean that is a resource
     // interface ProxiedInterface { String get(); }
     // @Path("resource") class MyResource implements ProxiedInterface {
     //     @GET String get() {...}
     // }
     //
     invokedMethod = interfaceBasedMethod;
  }

  Object result = null;
  try
  {
     result = invokedMethod.invoke(resource, args);
  }
  catch (IllegalAccessException e)
  {
     throw new InternalServerErrorException("Not allowed to reflect on method: " + method.toString(), e);
  }
```

the args of HttpResponse httpResponse is a NettyHttpResponse object,  so i can get channel by it.
so  how can i get the channel?

Answer (score 0):

You can't get the Netty Channel as it is an implementation detail

Comment: ok, i modify the implementation detail of HttpResponse, so get the Channel success, Thanks to Norman Maurer.